# Escritura de Archivos en Python

Tags: python

tengo que hacer un modulo que permita generar un archivo .csv en Python. Este es el codigo que he escrito y que funciona bien, pero a la vez me genera un salto de linea en el archivo que no quiero que esté. Les dejo el codigo y la imagen de como se genera el archivo. Saludos y gracias desde ya por su ayuda [image: No quiero el salto de linea que hay entre ambos datos]

```
def generar_archivo(self):
        Datos= []
        Lista= []

        archivo_inscriptos= open('Inscriptos.csv','w')
        for i in range(len(self.__inscripciones)):
            dni= self.__inscripciones[i].get_persona_DNI()
            idTaller= self.__inscripciones[i].get_taller_ID()
            fechaIns= self.__inscripciones[i].get_fecha_inscripcion()
            pago= self.__inscripciones[i].estado_de_pago()

            if (pago == False):
                p = 'Adeuda'
            else:
                p = 'Pago'

            Lista= [str(dni),str(idTaller),str(fechaIns),str(p)]
            Datos.append(Lista)

        with archivo_inscriptos:
            writer= csv.writer(archivo_inscriptos)
            writer.writerows(Datos)
        print ("ARCHIVO INSCRIPTOS GUARDADOS")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El módulo csv usa `\r\n` como fin de linea, pero en Windows los archivos en modo texto trasladan cada `\n` por `\r\n`, por lo que al final tienes `\r\r\n`.

La solución es usar el parámetro `newline` y asignarle una cadena vacía. Traducíon libre de la [documentación](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#id1):

> Si `csvfile` es un file-object, debe abrirse con `newline = ''`
>
> Si no se especifica `newline = ''`, los caracteres de nueva línea
>   incrustados dentro de campos acotados no se interpretarán
>   correctamente y en las plataformas que usan `\r\n` como fin de línea,
>   al escribir se agregará un `\r` adicional.

```
archivo_inscriptos= open('Inscriptos.csv', 'w', newline="")
```

Comment: Funcionó perfecto. Muchas gracias!